# Disable Submit button for demo

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

I am trying to disable the Submit button for a Tabbed Menu page for a demo account. Unfortunately each of the 3 menu tabs has the same button id - 'Mod0EditRecord'. I can't rename the button id nor can I use class instead, since it is rendered by an online database.

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="Mod0EditRecord" id="Mod0EditRecord">
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="Mod0EditRecord" id="Mod0EditRecord">
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="Mod0EditRecord" id="Mod0EditRecord">
```

I can successfully set the attribute of the first button to disabled as follows

```
if (login == 'demo.account')
{
document.getElementById('Mod0EditRecord').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
document.write("<br><p style=\"text-align:left; padding-left:100px; font-size:10px;\">** Update button is disabled for the demo **</p>");
} 
else
{
document.getElementById('Mod0EditRecord').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to set the attribute for the other two.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript dom manipulation library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.org) to traverse the HTML nodes and add classes/change ids as you like.

If you have to stick with those attributes in particular then you could do something like this in jQuery:

```
$('input[name="Mod0EditRecord"]').eq(0).attr('disabled','disabled') 
//this is the first input, change .eq(index) to the value you need
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of document.getElementById should be an array. And you can traverse through them.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('Mod0EditRecord');
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
    {
      elem[i].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    }
```

Or if you are using jquery, you can use .next() method to retrieve the other two elements.

Comment: Thanks devBinnooh for your response. Unfortunately, I dont think your suggestion will work because getElementById only returns the first matching element - which was my original problem. If the button was specified via "class" instead of "id", then one could use getElementsByName('Mod0EditRecord') and get the array as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.getElementById` , since that returns the first element with that ID. I wouldn't go with jQuery if you're using VanillaJS, since downloading a library just for this functionality is pretty useless.

This is what you go do: use `document.getElementsByTagName` to get all the `input`-types, check if it's from `type submit` and `disable` that.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    if(inputs[i].type === "submit") {
        var submitbtn = inputs[i];
        submitbtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w2WN/).

Comment: Thanks MarcoK. I agree this is a lightweight solution. I already had Jquery on my webpage for other things. So I ended up using Tony's solution. But if I didnt, I would prefer yours.